# Android - Facebook SDK - how to tell if user changed password or removed app from app settings on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-facebook

I was testing our app using test cases from Facebook's developers site.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow

Our app failed two following test cases:

> 5. Someone removes your app from Facebook via app settings and revisits your app. Your app should detect this and prompt the person
>      to log back in.
>
>    - Go to your app and tap on the "Log in with Facebook” button Tap OK to accept the read permissions (and OK again to accept write
>        permissions where applicable)
>    - Go to app settings on Facebook and remove your app
>    - Repeat steps 1-2 and verify that Facebook Login works
> 6. Someone changes the Facebook password after logging in with Facebook to your app In this case, your token will be invalid and you
>      should notify users that their Facebook session has expired and ask
>      them to log in again.
>
>    - Change your Facebook password and select “Log me out of other devices”
>    - Go to your app and tap on the "Log in with Facebook” button
>    - Tap OK to accept the read permissions (and OK again to accept write permissions where applicable)
>    - Go to app settings on Facebook and verify that the granted permissions are there

I have been trying to find the right method on the Facebook SDK for a way how to check this. Is there such method that would tell me that the user needs to log in again (in case of changing a password or removing the app from app settings on Facebook website)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a "me" API call. If that fails on OAuthException I can be sure that something is wrong with the user login state.

```
    Action<JSONObject, GraphResponse> facebookMeCallbackAction =
        delegate (JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse)
        {
            try
            {
                if (graphResponse.Error == null)
                {
                    // Do whatever we need to do in regards to Facebook
                }
                else
                {
                    if (graphResponse.Error.ErrorType.Equals(FacebookMeCallback.OAuthExceptionExceptionType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        // Something wrong is with the login state, ask for reconnection to Facebook, etc.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Something else went wrong
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Util.LogException(ex);
            }
        };

    using (var facebookCallback = new FacebookMeCallback(facebookMeCallbackAction))
    {
        var newMeRequest = GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken, facebookCallback);
        GraphRequest.ExecuteAndWait(newMeRequest);
    }
```

Here is the FacebookMeCallback class:

```
public class FacebookMeCallback : Java.Lang.Object, GraphRequest.IGraphJSONObjectCallback
    {
        public const string OAuthExceptionExceptionType = "OAuthException";

        private readonly Action<JSONObject, GraphResponse> onCompletedFacebookCallbackAction;

        public FacebookMeCallback(Action<JSONObject, GraphResponse> onCompletedFacebookCallbackAction)
        {
            this.onCompletedFacebookCallbackAction = onCompletedFacebookCallbackAction;
        }

        public void OnCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse)
        {
            if (onCompletedFacebookCallbackAction != null)
                onCompletedFacebookCallbackAction(jsonObject, graphResponse);
        }
    }
```