# How could i send user to login page in my android application if user changed the facebook password

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Im using facebook sdk for login in my android application. i have successfully login with facebook but i have changed the password in facebook then the logged android application should prompt for login again. i have followed the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android it shows only login procedure .

```
public class UserLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
LoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this, "success login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

I have attached code, please tell me what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Read out for [ProfileTracker Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ProfileTracker/) and also check [AccessTokenTracker Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/) for more control.
Try:

```
accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            }
        } ;

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {

            }
        };
```

Comment: i have put the code please help me in this @faisal-naseer

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022868/android-facebook-sdk-how-to-tell-if-user-changed-password-or-removed-app-fro